# Can't run jenkins job jenkins using ant

Tags: jenkins, ant

I have some job in jenkins and i need start it using ant

```
ant run
```

Build.xml

```
<project name="jenkins-facade" default="run" basedir=".">
  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
  <description>
    simple example build file
  </description>
  <property name="post.json.encoded" value=""/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <property name="post.json" value='{"parameter": [{"name":"foo_param", "value":"123"}]}'/>
    <urlencode name="post.json.encoded" value="${post.json}" />
  </target>

  <target name="run" depends="init"
    description="run jenkins job">
    <post to = "http://jankhost:8080/job/Test/buildWithParameters/"
      verbose="true" failonerror="true">
      <prop name="token" value="1234567"/>
      <prop name="json" value="${post.json.encoded}"/>
    </post>
  </target>
</project>
```

But when i run it i got 403 error. 
I need to run a task on your behalf, and not by anonymous. How can i do this? How to pass through the ant username and token?

[scr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU6N3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised/horrified that there's an Ant task to do HTTP POST requests, but looking at its [documentation](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/post_task.html), it appears that there's no way to set HTTP request headers, which you would need for a Jenkins API request like this.

So as an alternative, you could try setting the username and API token in the URL — I don't know whether the Ant task supports this, but you could try `http://<user>:<api_token>@jankhost:8080/job/Test/buildWithParameters/`

Another possibility, according to any `https://<jenkins>/job/<name>/api` page may be to use the secret token mechanism:

> Another alternative (but deprecated) is to configure the 'Trigger builds remotely' section in the job configuration. Then building or polling can be triggered by including a parameter called token in the request.

You can then include this secret token in the build URL itself.  However, as you have security enabled, this will not work out-of-the-box — you will need to install the [Build Token Root](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-token-root) plugin, and follow the instructions there.